# Can a code block include any number of statements?

Tags: c#

In C#, curly braces is to group code. 
So my question Is that the code block can include any number of statements? Whether in Methods, Class or loop statements....

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is called *block statement* in C# and *compound statement* in C/C++ from where C# borrowed most of its statements. You can see its definition for C++ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compound-statements-blocks?view=vs-2017).

You can see that definition of compound statement is recursive which allows you to have as many as you like statements inside even zero, including compound ones.

```
compound-statement:
    { statement-seq_opt }

statement-seq:
    statement
    statement-seq statement
```

And from C# standard (1.5 Statements):

> A ***block*** permits multiple statements to be written in contexts
>   where a single statement is allowed. A block consists of a list of
>   statements written between the delimiters { and }.

You are also asking about classes. Well, class declaration can contain as many member declarations as you like, if you mean that. But member declaration is not a statement per se, still some of member declarations, member functions, can include statements.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can include as many statements inside a block as you want regardless of whether it's within a method body, loop block, `if` block etc..

ideally, you should try to not write too much code inside a single block as it becomes unreadable and harder to maintain thus it's a good practice to separate a huge block of code into small chunks of reusable/executable code by using functions/methods.

Comment: Each block of statement have own scope and executed line by line. Right?